# Save state of the options settings (cocos2d)

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

i've a question, i want that my game save the state of the settings in my options scene, for example..if i switch off the music with clicking on the music button, the music will be off and the written under the music image will be "music off" also if i change the scene ,the settings remain the same as i set and until here is ok....but when i restart the application, the settings returning as before, with music on and "music on" in the written under music image, so how can i do to fix this?

Comment: use NSUserDefaults to save status of music on/off

Comment: a bit of your code would be nice ... how do you expect people to 'fix it' if they have zero context on what and how you have proceeded so far ?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest and most common way to achieve that is NSUserDefaults.

firstly, you have to register defaults at first launch (in applicationDidFinishLaunch).

```
 NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
if (![userDefaults boolForKey:@"hasLaunchedOnce"]) {
            [userDefaults setBool:YES forKey:@"hasLaunchedOnce"];
            NSDictionary* defaults = [NSDictionary dictionary];
            [defaults setValue:@YES forKey:@"musicOn"];
            [userDefaults registerDefaults:defaults];
    }
```

Then for example you set new value on button press

```
musicButton.block = ^(id sender) {
        NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[userDefaults setBool:YES forKey: @"musicOn"];
// [userDefaults synchronize]; // actually you dont really need to force it everytime, but if you want

    };
```

And if you want to check anywhere in your code if music is on you just do

```
  NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
 if ( [userDefaults boolForKey:@"musicOn"] ) { /* do something */}
```

Comment: Mark as answer if it was helpful to you!